# My Website not Working with ajaxcontroltoolkit 3.5 IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a website with asp.net C# when  hosted locally works fine.
When Used with IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 ajax control tool kit does not work properly. Can anyone help me please.

Error shown in FireBug:

```
 NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.acmeinfovision.com/Settings/ClientSalaryHeadSetting.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.5.60501.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3a61715ba4-0922-4e75-a2be-d80670612837%3af2c8e708%3ade1feab2%3a720a52bf%3af9cec9bc%3a589eaa30%3aa67c2700%3aab09e3fe%3a87104b7c%3a8613aea7%3a3202a5a2%3abe6fb298%3aaf404b5%3a698129cf%3abb25728f%3a289e72ab"
Client...89e72ab
Sys.Extended is undefined
[Break On This Error]   ...tl00_DropPanel"),"dynamicServicePath":"/Settings/ClientSalaryHeadSetting.aspx","...
```

---

Master Page Code Looks Like this

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="AcmePayRoll.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)" />
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)" />
    <title></title>
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/Stylesheet_mini.css")%>' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/ui-Redmond/jquery-ui_mini.css")%>' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/demo_table_jui_mini.css") %>' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/ColVis_mini.css")%>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/TableTools_mini.css") %>' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/TableTools_JUI_mini.css")%>' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='<%# this.ResolveCSS("~/css/ColReorder_mini.css")%>' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />

    <script src='<%# this.ResolveJS("~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src='<%# this.ResolveJS("~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js") %>' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src='<%# this.ResolveJS("~/js/Themeswither/TmemeSwither_mini.js") %>' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src='<%# this.ResolveJS("~/js/ScrollableGrid_mini.js") %>' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src='<%# this.ResolveJS("~/js/PayrollCommon_mini.js") %>' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src='<%# this.ResolveJS("~/js/jquery.table_navigation_mini.js")%>' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <link rel='SHORTCUT ICON' href='<%# this.ResolveUrl("~/Images/Acme-Logo.ICO")%>' />

    <script type="text/javascript">

     document.write("<div id='loading'><img id='pic1' src='<%#  this.ResolveUrl("~/Images/15.gif") %>' /><br>Please Wait...</div>");

        $(document).ready(function() { 
        var url='<%#  this.ResolveUrl("~/") %>';

            AddThemeSwither("ThemeSwither",url);
            ApplyCommonStyles();
            scrlsts();
            $("#contentdiv").height($(window).height());
            $("#contentdiv").width($(window).width());
        });

        function check()
        {
            var grid = $("<%# grid_clients.ClientID %>");
            $(grid).Scrollable({ ScrollHeight: 70 });
        }
         function help_click(e) { 
              var helpurl= $(e.parentNode).find("input[type='hidden']");  
              var val=helpurl.val();
              if(val!="")
              { 
                  window.open(val,'win');
              } 
        }
    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        #ThemeSwither
        {
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: auto;
            overflow: inherit;
            top: 5px;
            left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; background-color: #FDF8FF;" >
    <div style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%; height: 144px; top: 0; margin: 0;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="contentdiv" style="width: 100%; border-bottom-color: Black">
            <ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode ="Release"  EnablePageMethods ="true" CompositeScript-ScriptMode ="Release"  LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false">
            </ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID ="ScriptManager1" runat ="server" >
            </asp:ScriptManager>--%>
            <table width="100%" style="height: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr class="ui-state-hover" style="vertical-align: top; height: 8%">
                    <td style="width: 20%">
                        <div id="ThemeSwither">
                        </div>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDashboard" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Style="position: absolute;
                            margin-left: auto; overflow: inherit; top: 65px; left: 15px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/Dashboard48.png"
                            ToolTip="Dashboard" AlternateText="Dashboard" DescriptionUrl="~/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx"
                            OnClick="btnDashboard_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr style="vertical-align: top">
                                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbluserid" runat="server" CssClass="ui-state-hover" Text="User Id"
                                        Style="border: 0px; position: static; font-family: Cambria; font-size: medium"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 10%; vertical-align: top" align="right">
                                    <a href="" runat="server" id="cmdSignOut" style="font-family: Cambria; font-size: 15px;
                                        vertical-align: top">SignOut</a>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_help_url" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="helpbutton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/help-icon.png"
                                        Height="20px" Width="20px" ToolTip="Help" OnClientClick="help_click(this); return false;" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:Image ID="clientlogo" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="31px" ImageAlign="Bottom" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblclientid" runat="server" CssClass="ui-state-hover" Text="Client Id"
                                                Style="border: 0px; font-family: Cambria; font-size: larger"></asp:Label>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="DropDownExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblclient"
                                                            PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true"
                                                            CancelControlID="CancelSubmitCompanies" />
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lblclient" runat="server" ToolTip="Client List" Height="40px"
                                                            OnClientClick="check()" Width="40px" ImageUrl="~/Images/apartment-icon.png" Visible="false"
                                                            AccessKey="c" />
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="DropPanel" Style="display: none" runat="server" Width="200px" BackColor="#f4f4f4"
                                                    BorderStyle="Solid">
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <ajaxtoolkit:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblSelect"
                                                            DropDownControlID="DropPanel">
                                                        </ajaxtoolkit:DropDownExtender>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lblSelect" runat="server" ToolTip="Financial Year List" Height="35px"
                                                            Width="35px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar-icon.png" OnClick="lblSelect_Click"
                                                            AccessKey="y" />
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 83%; vertical-align: top">
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <div class="ui-widget-header" id="nav-menu">
                            <asp:Menu ID="MnuSiteMenus" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DynamicHoverStyle-CssClass="dmenuHover"
                                Font-Bold="false" AccessKey="n" Font-Names="Cambria" DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="ui-state-hover"
                                DynamicBottomSeparatorImageUrl="~/Images/LineSeparator.png" StaticItemFormatString="&amp;nbsp &amp;nbsp {0}">
                            </asp:Menu>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: center" class="ui-state-hover">
                            <asp:Label ID="mainlabel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="X-Large" Font-Names="cambria"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="border-left-width: 30px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #FDF8FF;
                            border-right-width: 30px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: #FDF8FF">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ui-state-hover" style="vertical-align: top; background-color: #FFEFDB;
                    height: 4%">
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
                        <div>
                            <p style="text-align: right; font-size: small; font-family: Cambria;">
                                <marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="2" width="100%">Copyright &copy; 2012 Acme Infovision Systems Pvt. Ltd. All Rights Reserved.</marquee>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#f4f4f4" Style="display: none; overflow: hidden;"
            Visible="false" BorderStyle="Solid">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelrptClientList" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: large">
                        <asp:Label ID="grid_label" runat="server" Text="List of Clients" CssClass="all_inputs_labels"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 220px; overflow: scroll">
                        <grid:MyGridView ID="grid_clients" ScrollWidthInpx="400" Width="600px" runat="server"
                            AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectedIndex="0" Font-Size="17px"
                            MouseHoverRowHighlightEnabled="true" CssClass="all_labels_inputs" ColumnNoToTrace="0">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="ClientName">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lb" Text='<%# Eval("ClientName")%>' runat="server" OnClick="lbtn1_Click" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Contact">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientId" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="ClientId">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#3B4990" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="ui-state-hover" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="all_labels_inputs ui-state-hover" Font-Bold="True" />
                        </grid:MyGridView>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelSubmitCompanies" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question is too complicate and you are not focus us to the real problem, nether give us also the rendered html page to see whats actually you render on the page. Also I have found some bugs on your javascript, and bad design. Its looks complicate page, when is start to not working ? because for sure you didnt make it at ones.

Comment: one more, this is the master page, what is the actually page that using this page that did have the problem ?

Comment: You have post the same question 3 times....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net 3.5 Ajaxcontroltoolkit 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910131/asp-net-3-5-ajaxcontroltoolkit-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sys.Extended is undefined
but it is working on local IIS 6, IIS 7 IIS 7.5
```

From all your questions that are the same with this one I conclude that you have forget to include the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` on your bin directory.

If you do have included then you did not have correct registered on your web.config on the different server.